# Regular Expression - Repeating Groups

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to read a log file and extract some machine/setting information using regular expressions. Here is a sample from the log:

```
...
COMPUTER INFO:
 Computer Name:                 TESTCMP02
 Windows User Name:             testUser99
 Time Since Last Reboot:        405 Minutes
 Processor:                     (2 processors) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            5160  @ 3.00GHz
 OS Version:                    5.1 .number 2600:Service Pack 2
 Memory:                        RAM: 48% used, 3069.6 MB total, 1567.3 MB free
 ServerTimeOffSet:              -146 Seconds 
 Use Local Time for Log:        True

INITIAL SETTINGS:
 Command Line:                  /SKIPUPDATES
 Remote Online:                 True
 INI File:                      c:\demoapp\system\DEMOAPP.INI
 DatabaseName:                  testdb
 SQL Server:                    10.254.58.1
 SQL UserName:                  SQLUser
 ODBC Source:                   TestODBC
 Dynamic ODBC (not defined):    True
...
```

I would like to capture each 'block' of data, using the header as one group, and the data as a second (i.e. "COMPUTER INFO", "Computer Name:.......") and repeat this for each block. The expression if have so far is

```
(?s)(\p{Lu}{1,} \p{Lu}{1,}:\r\n)(.*\r\n\r\n)
```

This pulls out the block into the groups like it should, which is great. But I need to have it repeat the capture, which I can't seem to get. I've tried several grouping expressions, including:

```
(?s)(?:(\p{Lu}{1,} \p{Lu}{1,}:\r\n)(.*\r\n\r\n))*
```

which would seem to be correct, but I get back lots of NULL result groups with empty group item values. I'm using the .Net RegEx class to apply the expressions, can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible to have repeated groups.  The group will contain the last match.

You'll need to break this into two problems.  First, find each section:

```
new Regex(@"(?>^[A-Z\s]+:\s*$)\s*(?:(?!^\S).)*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

And then, within each match, use another regex to match each field/value into groups:

```
new Regex(@"^\s+(?<name>[^:]*):\s*(?<value>.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

---

The code to use this would look something like this:

```
Regex sectionRegex = new Regex(@"(?>^[A-Z\s]+:\s*$)\s*(?:(?!^\S).)*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex nameValueRegex = new Regex(@"^\s+(?<name>[^:]*):\s*(?<value>.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection sections = sectionRegex.Matches(logData);
foreach (Match section in sections)
{
    MatchCollection nameValues = nameValueRegex.Matches(section.ToString());
    foreach (Match nameValue in nameValues)
    {
        string name = nameValue.Groups["name"].Value;
        string value = nameValue.Groups["value"].Value;
        // OK, do something here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the approach, but the first expressions is not returning matching groups, and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the first case, you're not getting a group, you're just getting a match.  I'll add more code to the example.

Comment: I appologize. One I did this in code, it worked like a charm. I was trying the examples by themselves in Expresso. It must be the Singleline|Multiline options, which I will have to explore in more detail so I can understand how they make the expressions work. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?<header>[^:]+:)(?<content>[^\r\n]+)?\r\n)+
```

or, if you have empty lines between items:

```
(((?<header>[^:]+:)(?<content>[^\r\n]+)?\r\n)|\r\n)+
```

Comment: Sorry...that didn't work at all. Likely due to the .Net parsing engine. I am running my expressions through Expresso to simulate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about it. This would allow you to get the value of a specific group easily but the expression would be a bit more complicated. I add line feeds to make it easier to read. Here is the start:

```
COMPUTER INFO:.*Computer Name:\s*(?<ComputerName>[\w\s]+).*Windows User Name:\s*(?<WindowUserName>[\w\s]+).*Time Since Last Reboot:\s*(?<TimeSinceLastReboot>[\w\s]+).* (?# This continues on through each of the lines... )
```

with Comiled, IgnoreCase, SingleLine, and CultureInvariant

Then you would be able to match this via the groups ex:

```
string computerName = match.Group["ComputerName"].Value;
string windowUserName = match.Group["WindowUserName"].Value;
// etc.
```

Comment: I had thought about doing that, but the groups aren't finite. The developer may add more blocks later, or some may be missing. I can identify the start of the group of blocks, but need to process any number of them.

Answer (score 1):

Some links regarding repeating groups in regular expressions:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html
- http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/856077-how-get-all-repeated-group-regular-expression